# Result of the integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, line-integrals

$$\int_{C} \overline z \operatorname{Im}(z^2)dz,$$ Where C is $\frac{1}{4}$of a circle starting from point $Ri$ to point 
$R$. I calculated this using parametrization:  $$\gamma(t) = Re^{it}$$ from $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ to t=$0$
and got answer $$ -\frac{(2i+2)*R^3}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you very much that you have decided to disseminate your result. But do you have any question?

Comment: Not quite correct. $\gamma'(t)$ from $dz = \gamma'(t) dt$ is missing.